# Google map API anchor links to get location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have little problem with google map api.

I successfully embedded google map v.3 following this page( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/ ).

And now I want to put some links in the same page and when I click a link, pinpoint the location in the map. And also show my custom map pin icon.

ex.
...

```
<a href="link to get this place's location">Blah Blah City Convention Center</a>
<a href="link to get this place's location2">Blah Blah Shopping Mall</a>
```

If anybody know the official page explains this or some good tutorial sites, please let me know.

i made jsfiddle page to start with. feel free to modify :)

http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/NrYqA/

thank you.

Comment: What you exactly want to do on click of a hyper link??
1)you want to add marker to map?
2)you want to show/open info window on some marker??
3)Both?

Comment: @K.P. I want to do 3)both. I want the map to move to the desired location and the marker too when I click the hyperlink. To do so, my guess is do something like putting latitude and longitude of the location to href? ex. `a href="google.map.latLng(123.45,67.890)"`

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding marker to the map and adding events to each marker that time (when adding events to this marker) call below method with your map,marker and id of your hyper link.

```
function attachEvents(map, myMarker, linkID) {
      var markerRelDivObj = document.getElementById(linkID);
      if (markerRelDivObj) {
          markerRelDivObj.onmouseover = function () {
              if (!map.getBounds().contains(myMarker.getPosition())) {
                  map.panTo(myMarker.getPosition());
              }
              google.maps.event.trigger(myMarker, 'mouseover');
          };

          markerRelDivObj.onmouseout = function () {
                  google.maps.event.trigger(myMarker, 'mouseout');
          };
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I did to create two links which made the map move and zoom.

`You can <a href="#" 
onclick="oMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(20, 14.2));oMap.setZoom(2);">
zoom out to see the global perspective</a> 
or <a href="#" 
onclick="oMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(54, -4));oMap.setZoom(6);">
see the UK here</a>`.

This assumes your script block has already set up an object called `oMap`.